# access controller based on optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing WebAPI controller method.

```
 [SwaggerDefaultResponse]
 [HttpGet, Route("{id:int}", Name = "GetDataId")]
 public IHttpActionResult Get(long id)
  { 
      //This method returns a full Data
  }
```

I have to write granular WebAPI.
We are planning to have a route like below:

```
/V1/MYdATA/{DataId}?DataBasic=true
```

If `DataBasic=true`
then I should invoke a new method to get "Basic Data" ---
and if `DataBasic=false` then my existing Full data should be returned i.e. existing method should be invoked.

Can I get some idea for this as how to implement this in code?

Comment: is the method inside the same control or a different controller?

Comment: same inside same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebAPI .NET - POST request filter by parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090748/webapi-net-post-request-filter-by-parameters)

Comment: @pankaj added an aswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(long id, bool DataBasic)
{ 
    if (!DataBasic)
    {
        //This method returns a full Data
    }
    else
    {
       //Method Retrieving new data
    }
}
```

different controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(model.Databasic ? "GetNew" : "GetFull", "ControllerName", new {id = model.Id}))
{
        <input type="submit" name="Get" />
}


public IHttpActionResult GetNew(long? id)
{ 

    //Method Retrieving new data

}

public IHttpActionResult GetFull(long id)
{ 
    //This method returns a full Data
}
```

Comment: what change do i need to bring on my route

Comment: @pankaj edited my answer or you could search here on how to work with multiple paramaters

Comment: I am able to solve my problem by keeping old method as it is and creating a new one with bool flags.